# Constructing string using react property and es6 template feature

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to construct the href using the react property and es6 template feature. My code is below however after rendering the subHeader in href is not replaced with its value.

```
subHeaders = this.props.subHeaders.map((subHeader, i) => {
    return <a className="articleSidebar__summaryText" href='#${subHeader}' key={i}>{subHeader}</a>;
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the right syntax in the `href` part.

Are you trying to get an output like `#something`? In that case, it should be:

```
href={`#${subHeader}`}
```

You need to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (``` `` ```) when you want to do string interpolation. And you need to use `{}` around the template literal because thats the syntax you need to use in order to set a prop to some JS expression instead of some literal string.